# gcc errors “No such file or directory”

Tags: c, gcc

Trying to compile a source code written in C.
Location of the code is: `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\prog\c\learn\GOODBYE.C`

In CMD I typed the code: `gcc goodbye.c -o goodbye`

Got this error:

```
gcc: error: goodbye.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I wanted the output to be named `goodbye`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your current directory in the CMD when launching gcc? And please don't spam tags next time.

Comment: It's "C:\Users\Chris". Sorry about the tags.

Comment: OK, are you seriously asking why gcc cannot find a file in some random directory unrelated to the one you're in, when you don't give it a path to it?

Comment: Oh wait....Ahhh. I'm so sorry, I'm new to C and i was following a text book. But is there a way i can directly put the path in gcc line in cmd? Instead of using "cd" first?

Comment: By the looks so far, this has nothing to do with C and is just about basic command-line usage.

Comment: I'll take that as a no. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you are running `gcc goodbye.c -o goodbye` while you are in the `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\prog\c\learn\` directory.

If the c file is named GOODBYE.c then you should run `gcc GOODBYE.c -o goodbye`

Answer (score 1):

Enter the name of the directory in which the program is located. Like if the program is in "D" drive, then open the VS Code terminal and enter "D:" (without quotation) and hit enter, and then rerun the code [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZFLD.png).

Answer (score 0):

what if you run `gcc "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\prog\c\learn\GOODBYE.C" -o goodbye`

I guess it could be the case sensitivity. Either rename the file or run `gcc GOODBYE.C -o goodbye`

Comment: Neither solution worked. Still giving the same error.

Comment: @UsamaAbdul What happens if you just replace `gcc` with `notepad.exe` and omit the `-o goodbye` part? Does that open the file in Notepad?

Comment: @Angew Yes it does, only if i'm in the correct directory. Which was the problem all along.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, I used:

```
gcc -o goodbye goodbye.o -no-pie
```