# Why can't GCC see my file in netbeans 8.2 (windows)?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, netbeans-8

Every time I try to run a c++ executable using netbeans 8.2 I get this error:

gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

building works and running the executable by double clicking on it in it's location works.
it's just whenever I try to run it through netbeans that this issue happens.

I also tried the recommended here but to no avail [gcc errors “No such file or directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870728/gcc-errors-no-such-file-or-directory/50870885)

please help!

Comment: can you get a "helloworld.cc" to compile and run?

Comment: I can run a simple helloworld.cpp yes